# How to sort databases alphabetically in DBeaver Database Navigator

Tags: dbeaver

In the Database Navigator the databases are not sorted alphabetically.

This is a pain to use when you have many databases on a server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To sort the databases alphabetically :

- go to the Window - Preferences menu
- click on "User Interface" (DBeaver or Database in older versions), then Navigator
- check "Order elements alphabetically"
- disconnect + connect each connection (or just restart DBeaver)

Comment: Since this answer was written, "Database" in the preferences menu appears to have been replaced with "DBeaver". Other steps are all still good.

Comment: You're right, I just updated my answer, thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

As of now the option has moved again:

- Window -> Preferences
- User Interface -> Navigator

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not correct for Mac at least.

To sort the databases alphabetically:

- In the top menu, click Window then Preferences.
- Expand the DBeaver section.
- Click on Navigator.
- Enable "Order elements alphabetically".
- Click "Apply and Close".

Notice your databases are sorted alphabetically.

If they're not, then disconnect and connect the connection, or just restart DBeaver.

Comment: Please could you make it a bit clearer how your answer is different.